# Drawing of polylines with Google Maps Directions API

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have managed to trace routes on the map, what I want to achieve is that the union between the polylines is rounded, or that there are no sharp cuts between strokes.

Achievement:

[image]

Line to which you want to arrive:

[image]

```
public void onDrawRoutes(final GoogleMap mMap) throws JSONException {

final JSONArray polyline = mArray.getJSONObject(mRoute).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < polyline.length(); i ++) {
            String points = null;
            try {
                points = polyline.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            lists.add(i, PolyUtil.decode(points));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lists.size(); j++) {
            List<LatLng> iterable = lists.get(j);
            mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .addAll(iterable)
                    .width(20)
                    .color(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.ligthBlue, null)).geodesic(true));
        }
    }
}.execute();

}
```